# How do I use a turtle in this situation

Tags: python

Hi I'm just learning coding so I have a question about the Turtle function.

In my assignment I am trying to use the turtle to move into a spiral not circular but in a square. Basically I am trying to spin the turtle using a while and for loop. Is that not the right move?

I have no coding that works so giving an example might not work. Sorry...

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJM5o.png)

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
You seem to want approval for a vague description of a problem approach; this is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what shape do you want to end up with but this following code will paint you a square

```
turtle.forward(50)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(50)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(50)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(50)
turtle.left(90)
```

as you can see I used 2 function here:

1. the forward function which moves the line forward in the arrow direction
2. the left function which spins the arrow left in the specified degree(90 for a square angel)

was that helpful? I'm here for more questions (:

Comment: You can use a for loop and a parameter x for the forward length and every loop decrease this parameter, let say x = x - 5 and then repeat the loop of creating a square

Answer (score 0):

```
#if you want to make square spiral in python then u must use this

import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
side = 200
for i in range(100):

  t.forward(side)
  t.right(90) #Exterior angle of a square is 90 degree
  side = side - 2
```